# How to prove $S^\dagger\neq S$ in context of transformations in Dirac equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

We know that $S^{-1}=\gamma^0S^\dagger\gamma^0$ and not equal to $S^\dagger$. How to explicitly prove this? I have searched the books but could not find this and am at a loss on how to proceed. Even some pointers would be helpful.

Comment: May you provide the definition of S?

Comment: S=exp$(−\frac{i}{4}ω_{μν}σ^{μν})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $S = \exp\left(-\frac i4\omega_{\mu\nu}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\right)$, where $\sigma^{\mu\nu} = \frac i2[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu]$. This gives $S^\dagger = \exp\left(\frac i4\omega_{\mu\nu}\sigma^{\mu\nu\dagger}\right)$. Now, try to prove $\sigma^{\mu\nu\dagger} = \gamma^0\sigma^{\mu\nu}\gamma^0$ which will give the desired result.

Comment: The $ω_{μν}$ is supposed to be antisymmetric then on taking a hermitian conjugate why it does not introduce a negative sign?